# Hash missing value, throwing exception

Tags: ruby

I have a hash which looks like this:

```
items:
    item:
        attribute_a: cheese
        attribute_b: bacon
    item:
        attribute_a: salmon
    item:
        attribute_a: mushrooms
        attribute_b: steak
```

I would like to get the value of `attribute_b`, I'm using the following:

```
if (result['attribute_b'])
  // do something
end
```

However if `attribute_b` is missing, I get an error:

```
The Identifier specified does not exist, undefined method '[] for nil:NilClass'
```

What is the (best) correct way to check if `attribute_b` exists?

Comment: At what line exactly do you get this error? What's a `result`?

Comment: Your comment syntax is invalid. And you can omit parentheses in `if` condition.

Comment: To be specific, I don't believe the syntax is *invalid* -- however it's true that it's not needed. It's appropriate to use parentheses for clarification if you believe it's clearer. In this case it probably doesn't make a difference so leaving them off may be the best approach. I think it's up to you.

Comment: It was my belief that is valid syntax and more a question of style and clarity. Do you disagree? Did I miss something?

Comment: I was talking about comments. Single-line comments in ruby start with `#`, not `//`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if you're getting the error not upon accessing the attribute `'attribute_b'`, but because `result` is nil.

```
The Identifier specified does not exist, undefined method [] for nil:NilClass`
```

It's saying you're calling the method `[]` on a nil value. The only thing you're calling '`[]`' on is `result`.

The way you're accessing `'attribute_b'` is acceptable in general -- I might be more specific and say:

```
if (result && result.has_key? 'attribute_b')
 // do something
end
```

This will make sure that `result` exists as well as making sure the attribute is not null.

Comment: Doesn't "The Identifier specified does not exist" part confuse you? There's something more going on there than just simple hash access.

Comment: It's better to use `result.has_key? 'attribute_b'` instead of `!result['attribute_b'].nil?`, because in some situations `nil` value can be valid.

Comment: Possibly. But I think it's clear that he's probably got a null `result` so my first thought would be to determine why. You may be correct in that it's something outside what we're seeing here.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your YAML structure looks bad (is it YAML?). You cannot have a hash with more than one element with the key `item`, because the key must be unique. You should use an array instead.

I suggest you structure you YAML along the lines of this here:

```
items:
  -
    attribute_a: cheese
    attribute_b: bacon
  -
    attribute_a: salmon
  -
    attribute_a: mushrooms
    attribute_b: steak
```

Then you can do

```
require 'yaml'
result = YAML.load(File.open 'foo.yml')
result['items'][0]['attribute_b']
=> "bacon"
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm doing thing.to_yaml in the real code. I just fudged how it's structured to simplify the question.

Comment: got your question wrong… but `result && result.has_key?` is the way to go.

Comment: ah I think someone else edited my question to make it clearer for everyone, thanks tho!